# How to create Firebase push Notification Payload on firebase function for flutter push Notification?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am creating a flutter application in which I have used cloud firestore as a backend. I want to trigger push notification along with data of multiple data types like array, maps , string and image which will display in notification when event is added to event collection.

I have written following function which is working fine for normal notification with out image and arrays and maps data types.

```
exports.eventPushNotification = functions.firestore.document('events/{eventid}').onCreate(async (snaphot, context) => {
    if(snaphot.empty){
        console.log("No data");
        return;
    }

    const eventData = snaphot.data();
    const dateavailable = eventData.available_dates;
    const ticketavailable = eventData.availbale_tickets;
    const coverImage = eventData.availbale_tickets;
    const created_at = eventData.created_at;
    const description = eventData.description;
    const title = eventData.title;
    const updated_at = eventData.updated_at;
    const venue = eventData.venue;
    var tokens =[];
    const deviceTokens =  await db.collection('DeviceTokens').get();
    console.log("Device tokens: ", deviceTokens.toString);
    for(var token of deviceTokens.docs)
    {
        tokens.push(token.data().token);
    }
    

    var payload = {
        notification : {title: "New Event Created", body: "Click here to see the event" },
        data: {
            click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
            message:"Sample Push Message",
            availableDatess : "afsdfa",
            availbale_tickets: "sdfsfa",
            cover: "sfsadf",
            created_at: "dsafsafs",
            description : "safasfs",
            title:"afdasfa",
            updated_at: "afasdfa",
            venue : "afdasf",
                    }
    }

    try{
        const respnse = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens,payload);
        console.log("Notification sent successfully");
    }
    catch(e){console.log("error while sending push notification", e.toString());
    }
}
);
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far for the other data types?

Comment: @YeriPelona Thank you for your question. Finally I am able to pass objects and map data types by converting them into string using JSON.stringify() function.

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference and as mentioned by @ranjit in their comment:

> You can do this by converting objects and map data types into string using JSON.stringify() function.